# How to print particular index to UpperCase and LowerCase

Tags: java

I would like to know how to print a particular index to Upper and Lower Case?

I don't know for the particular index to change?

**For single index this is the code...**

```
public class UpperAndLowerCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input="India";

        int index=input.indexOf('i');
        String result=input.substring(0,index)+input.substring(index,index+1).toUpperCase()+input.substring(index+1);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

The output of this program is : IndIa

But I want the output like this:  **indIa** (In a given input String, first 'I' to 'i' and next 'i' to 'I')

Comment: Do you want a particular index to change case or a particular letter?

Comment: I want particular index to change.

Answer (score 4):

Below is generic implementation which will give you expected result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "India";

    String newInput = replaceCharacterToUpperCase(input, 'i', true);
    System.out.println(newInput);

    String newInput2 = replaceCharacterToLowerCase(newInput, 'I', false);
    System.out.println(newInput2);
}

/**
 * 
 * @param input: Input string to work on.
 * @param c: Character to convert case
 * @param isAllOccurance: Whether to replace all occurrence or single occurrence 
 * @return
 */
private static String replaceCharacterToUpperCase(String input, char c, boolean isAllOccurance) {
     int index = input.indexOf(c);
     if(isAllOccurance){
         return input.replace(input.charAt(index), Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(index)));
     } else{
         return input.replaceFirst(Character.toString(input.charAt(index)), Character.toString(Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(index))));
     }
}

/**
 * 
 * @param input: Input string to work on.
 * @param c: Character to convert case
 * @param isAllOccurance: Whether to replace all occurrence or single occurrence 
 * @return
 */
private static String replaceCharacterToLowerCase(String input, char c, boolean isAllOccurance) {
     int index = input.indexOf(c);
     if(isAllOccurance){
         return input.replace(input.charAt(index), Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(index)));
     } else{
         return input.replaceFirst(Character.toString(input.charAt(index)), Character.toString(Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(index))));
     }
}
```

*Disclaimer: This is not tested exhaustively to cover all possible requirements or scenarios anybody can have, so on basis of your special requirement you may need to tweak the things a bit.*

---

Basically to replace single character in a String, you can use below code:

```
int index=input.indexOf('i');
        String newInput = input.replace(input.charAt(index), Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(index)));
```

---

There are many methods in `String` class which lets you do replacements, based on your requirement like whether character or string, first occurrenceor all occurrence. [Methods like](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

- `replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`
- `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`
- `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`

Comment: Buddy, are you good with this. Please let me know in case of any question.